# Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ such that $Ax = 0$ only has the trivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

(I) $A^Tx = 0$ only has the trivial solution.
(II) $A^{-1}x = 0$ only has the trivial solution.

Which of the above statements is/are always true?

Comment: What do you know about determinants?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let consider that $A$ is full rank and then

- the columns and the rows of $A$ are linearly independent vectors
- $A$ is invertible and then $Ax=0\implies A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}0$

Answer (score 0):

For $(i)$ recall that $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^T$ is invertible, the inverse being $(A^{-1})^T$.
\begin{align}
Ax = 0 \text{ has only the trivial solution } &\iff A\text{ is invertible} \\
&\iff A^T\text{ is invertible} \\
&\iff A^Tx = 0 \text{ has only the trivial solution }
\end{align}

For $(ii)$, recall that $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^{-1}$ is invertible, the inverse being $A$ itself.

\begin{align}
Ax = 0 \text{ has only the trivial solution } &\iff A\text{ is invertible} \\
&\iff A^{-1}\text{ is invertible} \\
&\iff A^{-1}x = 0 \text{ has only the trivial solution }
\end{align}